# How to remove disturbing white space on small devices using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a static html page, unfortunately when when I run my page and check responsiveness, I see white space on the right side of of my page, I followed many solution here in stack overflow by adding the following code:

inline I tried to add

```
html, body {
    font: normal 16px sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but this didn't work. I tried to add this in my CSS file:

```
html, body {
  font: normal 16px sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

also didn't work. here is the page I am building: [demo](http://html-dev.webcrafters.pl/)

What is wrong with my page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the `.Navbar` element which exceedes the 100% of the viewport

[image]

Since its left offset is `30px` instead of `width: 100%` set to `width: calc(100% - 30px)` (or alternatively, set `left: 0`) and rearrange the space/size of the inner elements

Answer (score 0):

Add position: relative in your css body and "!important" in your margin see code below.

```
html, body {
  font: normal 16px sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Then move your menu a little bit to the right use this update your .main-banner set the new value for padding

```
.main-banner {
    background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 65px;
```